# Sharpness and contrast at small resolution pictures

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, resolution

Ok, so maybe this has nothing to do with Adobe Illustrator or design, maybe problem is with WordPress I don't know...

But, I created a logo with Adobe Illustrator, and it looks great. Artboard and artwork itself is in high resolution. And I need to place that logo on my WordPress site. My theme is recommended me a 190x50 px resolution for logo. And when I export AI artwork in JPG or PNG, with that resolution and place it on my web site it looks blurry, not sharp, with bad contrast...but when I export it with higher resolution it look good.

How can I get small picture, with small resolution, but to maintain good contrast and good sharpness?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you post the 190 x 50px image so we can see the problem?  Also are you viewing it on a computer with a high definition screen, and if so, is there any system zoom set on your computer?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing your export settings and the code that is displaying the image.

Comment: 190x50px isn't much. Lots of details could be lost depending on the image. Does the logo on the website look different than the image you export? You say that it looks better with a higher resolution image. Do you mean it looks better on your website or when opening the image in an image viewer? If it's the first, why not just use the hires image on your website?

Comment: Wolf, yes logo on website looks different than the same image logo opened with image viewer.  Both resolutions higher and lower looks ok in image viewer. But on website only higer resolution looks normal. But that higer resolution makes the logo too big and design is bad.

Comment: AndrewH, export settings both for jpg and png formats are default. Also code is default...came with the theme.

Comment: Billy, I will ask for permission to post a logo. As I said, on the same screen, from image viewer image logo looks ok, but on website not so good.

Comment: @John It doesn't have to be the actual logo, just something similar showing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution could be to insert a SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) file, that is resolution-independent and can scale to any dimension without losing quality, but WordPress doesn't support this format.

However, there are ways to avoid this limitation and two of them are described on this [page](https://themeisle.com/blog/add-svg-to-wordpress/).

On this [page](https://blog.tbhcreative.com/2017/06/benefits-of-using-svg.html) are illustrated the benefits of using SVG.

Answer (score 0):

No, its neither a problem with illustrator nor the size. Designing small icons just simply requires a totally new mental mindset in how things are created.

First you need to mind your actual pixels. You need to be looking at that image at the size it is going to export as. There is no way around this. Yes vector graphics scale quite well, but only at bigger scales. Once individual pixels contribution starts to be a issue you need account for that. Meaning that the image is prepared for that resolution. No way around this, its way too easy to drop below the sampling limit.